# Define assembly for extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm trying to use extension method, but the method is defined twice with same name. 
Let's say `A.Extensions.Ext()` and `B.Extensions.Ext()` I need both references in my class and when trying

```
using A.Extensions;
using B.Extensions;
class C
{
    public void Main()
    {
        somevalue.Ext();
    }
}
```

I want to somehow define which method to use and I don't know how to do that.
Thanks for help!

Comment: You can call the method explicitly, passing the object you want to act on as the first argument. You don't have to use the extension syntax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987541/explicitly-use-extension-method

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283583/extension-methods-conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to choose an extension method to be used

Assume you have two classes with extension methods for string

```
public static class Extension1
    {
        public static string GetLowerCaseResult(this string str)
        {
            return str.ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }

    public static class Extension2
    {
        public static string GetLowerCaseResult(this string str)
        {
            return str.ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
```

to call it in Main method you have to explicitly specify class and method in this way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = "QWERTY";
            Extension2.GetLowerCaseResult(str);
            Console.Read();
        }
```